# is it possible to create SWF files with PHP?

Tags: php, flash, dynamically-generated

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Customizable / Dynamic SWF generation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469684/customizable-dynamic-swf-generation)

I like to generate dynamically single SWF files.

I want to include images and some tweens.

Answer (score 0):

Use flashvars to pass parameters in embedding to flash and handle them in flash with

```
root.loaderInfo.parameters
```

Answer (score 0):

yes

Look up:
http://www.emarksoft.com/php-flash-CreatePolygon.htm

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used Ming myself, but seen a couple of questions about it here at stackoverflow - "Ming is an open-source (LGPL) library which allows you to create SWF ("Flash") format movies.":

http://php.net/manual/en/book.ming.php